# Ansible conditional variable doesn't work

Tags: ansible

Here is a simple ansible playbook example that makes use of conditionals:

```yaml
---

- name:
  hosts: web_servers
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: test
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ '-s' if silent_mode==true else '' }}"
```

I use it with this inventory:

```ini
[all:vars]
silent_mode=true

[web_servers]
srv1 ansible_host=1.2.3.4
```

My issue is the following: whichever the value of `silent_mode` in the inventory is, the debug message is always empty.

Even weirder: when I only output the `silent_mode` variable's content, the value is correct:

```yaml
---

- name:
  hosts: web_servers
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: test
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      #msg: "{{ '-s' if silent_mode==true else '' }}"
      msg: "{{ silent_mode }}"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible conditionals are evaluated using Python, so every boolean must be either `True` or `False` (with a capital first letter).

The following works:

```ini
[all:vars]
silent_mode=True

[web_servers]
srv1 ansible_host=1.2.3.4
```

```yaml
---

- name:
  hosts: web_servers
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: test
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ '-s' if silent_mode==True else '' }}"
```

Thanks to `u/anaumann` on `r/ansible` for the tip.

Comment: `if something == True` is bad coding either way. You should do `if silent_mode`, only.